# Conditional OR in makefile

Tags: makefile, logic, conditional-statements, verbose

I'd like to enable a verbose compilation in my makefile, but I can't figure out how to make a conditional `OR`.

Let me explain: I want to be able to specify a *verbose* compilation either by setting `V=1` **or** `VERBOSE=1`. I want to keep `VERBOSE=1` available because we have some scripts that make use of it (and use other makefiles only aware of `VERBOSE`)

So the result must be that these two commands are the same:

```
make all VERBOSE=1 # pain to write
make all V=1
```

Now, my makefile looks like this today:

```
ifdef VERBOSE
[issue compilation commands with verbose mode]
endif
```

What I'd like to achieve is close to the preprocessor in C:

```
if defined(VERBOSE) || defined(V)
[issue compilation commands with verbose mode]
endif
```

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: ifeq http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656425/makefile-ifeq-logical-or

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I do like this:

```
ifneq "$(or $(LINUX_TARGET),$(OSX_TARGET))" ""

endif
```

Similar to the $(strip approach, but using the more intuitive **$(or** keyword

Comment: I switched to accept your answer,  because it is semantically exactly solving my issue.

Answer (score 7):

```
VERBOSE := $(or $(VERBOSE),$(V))
```

...then...

```
ifeq ($(VERBOSE),1)
#Conditional stuff
endif
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the conditional stuff in GNU make doesn't allow for ORs and ANDS. You could always do something like:

```
ifdef VERBOSE
DOVERBOSE = yes
endif
ifdef V
DOVERBOSE = yes
endif

ifeq( $DOVERBOSE, yes )
    main verbose stuff here
endif
```

but I don't see why you need to introduce the (hardly self documenting) define of V in the first place.

Comment: How about `ifdef V \ VERBOSE=v \ endif` and leave the rest as it is?

Comment: @Beta not bad as well! But I like your answer better.

Answer (score 4):

I like Neil Butterworth's approach, but if you really want to do it in the style you describe, this will give you OR:

```
ifneq "$(strip $(VERBOSE) $(V))" ""
[be verbose]
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, really late to the party, but I came across this, and wanted to add another solution for others who were looking how to add logic to makefiles:  basically, do the logic in a shell, and get the output that way.

```
ifneq ( $(shell ( [ $(VERBOSE) ] || [ $(V) ] ) && echo y ),)
```

it seems more convoluted, but if you have an if statement with many ands and ors, this offers a lot of flexibility, and would be easier to read than nested $(and .. $(or ...)) statements.

Comment: It does "offer a lot of flexibility"--except that it limits you to using the specific shell that you code it to (in your case, BASH)