# Makefile ifeq logical or

Tags: makefile

How do you perform a logical OR using make's `ifeq` operator?

e.g., I have (simplified):

```
ifeq ($(GCC_MINOR), 4)
    CFLAGS += -fno-strict-overflow
endif
ifeq ($(GCC_MINOR), 5)
    CFLAGS += -fno-strict-overflow
endif
```

but would like to consolidate these lines.

(yes, yes, autotools, configure, etc etc; too heavy-handed for the current situation, would like to keep everything within the Makefile here)

[logical opposite of this question: [How to Use of Multiple condition in 'ifeq' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451477/how-to-use-of-multiple-condition-in-ifeq-statement) ]

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Complex conditions check in Makefile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584872/complex-conditions-check-in-makefile)*.

Comment: Don't think it's a dupe, the linked question relates to chaining `ifdef` operators, this question is related to chaining `ifeq` operators, similar, but the answers are definitely different.

Comment: Similar to [Is there a logical `OR` operator for the `ifneq`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8296723/471376)

Answer (score 150, accepted):

As found on the mailing list archive,

- [http://osdir.com/ml/gnu.make.windows/2004-03/msg00063.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20160318170754/http://osdir.com/ml/gnu.make.windows/2004-03/msg00063.html)
- [http://osdir.com/ml/gnu.make.general/2005-10/msg00064.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20161016194211/http://osdir.com/ml/gnu.make.general/2005-10/msg00064.html)

one can use the `filter` function.

For example

```
ifeq ($(GCC_MINOR),$(filter $(GCC_MINOR),4 5))
```

`filter X, A B` will return those of A,B that are equal to X.
Note, while this is not relevant in the above example, this is a XOR operation. I.e. if you instead have something like:

```
ifeq (4, $(filter 4, $(VAR1) $(VAR2)))
```

And then do e.g. `make VAR1=4 VAR2=4`, the filter will return `4 4`, which is not equal to `4`.

A variation that performs an OR operation instead is:

```
ifneq (,$(filter $(GCC_MINOR),4 5))
```

where a negative comparison against an empty string is used instead (`filter` will return en empty string if `GCC_MINOR` doesn't match the arguments). Using the `VAR1`/`VAR2` example it would look like this:

```
ifneq (, $(filter 4, $(VAR1) $(VAR2)))
```

The downside to those methods is that you have to be sure that these arguments will always be single words. For example, if `VAR1` is `4 foo`, the filter result is still `4`, and the `ifneq` expression is still true. If `VAR1` is `4 5`, the filter result is `4 5` and the `ifneq` expression is true.

One easy alternative is to just put the same operation in both the `ifeq` and `else ifeq` branch, e.g. like this:

```
ifeq ($(GCC_MINOR),4)
    @echo Supported version
else ifeq ($(GCC_MINOR),5)
    @echo Supported version
else
    @echo Unsupported version
endif
```

Comment: A late note: in the two variations you have above, the first will resolve to true if $(GCC_MINOR) is blank, whereas the second will not (thus the second is the better solution generically speaking).

Comment: Actually, it should be `ifneq (,$(filter 4 5,$(GCC_MINOR)))` :)

Comment: Perhaps it's better to leave as-is for simplicity?

Comment: Another note: This doesn't work as a *general* OR statement. We have something where we want to check `if(flagA == TRUE || flagB == true)`, but if you do `$(filter true, $(flagA) $(flagB)` and both are true, you get `ifeq(true, true true)`

Answer (score 36):

You can introduce another variable.  It doesnt consolidate both checks, but it at least avoids having to put the body in twice:

```
do_it = 
ifeq ($(GCC_MINOR), 4)
    do_it = yes
endif
ifeq ($(GCC_MINOR), 5)
    do_it = yes
endif
ifdef do_it
    CFLAGS += -fno-strict-overflow
endif
```

Comment: The maintainability of this at scale doesn't seem very good to me :/

Then again, once we start talking scale, I guess we're talking autotools

Comment: @Pat: I rather prefer this approach where I can separate the assignment in one place in the Makefile, possibly comparing against more values using ifeq/else ifeq/else, rather than using the filter function that could just make awfully long hard to read lines.

Answer (score 20):

I don't think there's a concise, sensible way to do that, but there are verbose, sensible ways (such as Foo Bah's) and concise, pathological ways, such as

```
ifneq (,$(findstring $(GCC_MINOR),4-5))
    CFLAGS += -fno-strict-overflow
endif
```

(which will execute the command provided that the string $(GCC_MINOR) appears inside the string 4-5).

Comment: For better or worse (probably worse), just the kind of dirty hack I was looking for; thanks

Comment: I don't think this is pathological at all, other than the fact that *everything* in a Makefile is pathological. It's really quite elegant. I've read four or five different ways to accomplish this, and yours is by far the easiest to understand.

Answer (score 11):

Here more flexible variant: it uses external shell, but allows to check for arbitrary conditions:

```
ifeq ($(shell test ".$(GCC_MINOR)" = .4  -o  \
                   ".$(GCC_MINOR)" = .5  -o  \
                   ".$(TODAY)"     = .Friday  &&  printf "true"), true)
    CFLAGS += -fno-strict-overflow
endif
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that `ifeq ($(GCC_MINOR),$(filter $(GCC_MINOR),4 5))` will catch the case where GCC_MINOR is not defined at all.

If you want to catch GCC_MINOR==4 or GCC_MINOR==5 this will do trick:

```
ifneq ($(filter $(GCC_MINOR),4 5),)
    echo "def"
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ifeq ($(GCC_MINOR), 4)
>     CFLAGS += -fno-strict-overflow
> endif
> ifeq ($(GCC_MINOR), 5)
>     CFLAGS += -fno-strict-overflow
> endif
> ```

Another you can consider using in this case is:

```
GCC42_OR_LATER = $(shell $(CXX) -v 2>&1 | $(EGREP) -c "^gcc version (4.[2-9]|[5-9])")

# -Wstrict-overflow: http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/120
ifeq ($(GCC42_OR_LATER),1)
  CFLAGS += -Wstrict-overflow
endif
```

I actually use the same in my code because I don't want to maintain a separate `config` or `Configure`.

But you have to use a portable, non-anemic `make`, like GNU make (`gmake`), and not Posix's `make`.

And it does not address the issue of logical `AND` and `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you are looking to logically "or" several boolean flags together, one practical hack can be to simply let strings concatenate: **if** the end result is an empty string, **then** none of the options were true, **else** non-empty **then** *at least* one of them was enabled:

```
# Use `docker build --pull` in case either `PULL=whatever` is set OR if the `CI` environment variable is present.
ifneq ($(PULL)$(CI),)
PULL_OR_NOT := --pull
endif

build:
    docker build $(PULL_OR_NOT)
```