# Using ifeq with multiple options

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want check for a condition in makefile using ifeq,  & not sure how to go about:

```
ifeq ( cond1 = yes || cond2 = yes )   
  set value x = 1;   
else  
  set value x = 2;  
endif
```

Please suggest the proper way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Makefile ifeq logical or](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656425/makefile-ifeq-logical-or)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ifeq ($(filter $(cond1) $(cond2),yes),)
    x := 2
else  
    x := 1
endif
```

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the correct answer given above:if you want to check if x=4 or x=6

```
ifeq ($(x),$(filter $(x),4 6))   
   x is either 4 or 6. do whatever you like with it
else  
   x is neither 4 nor 6  
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate answer is:

```
ifneq (,$(filter yes,$(cond1) $(cond2)))   
   x := 1
else  
   x := 2
endif
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.