# Makefile OR condition

Tags: linux, makefile

I want to have multiple if condition and want to combine.

```
ifeq ($(TAG1), on)
LD_FLAGS += -ltestlibrary
endif
ifeq ($(TAG2), on)
LD_FLAGS += -ltestlibrary
endif
```

I want to do some thing like:

```
ifeq ($(TAG1) || $(TAG2), on)
LD_FLAGS += -ltestlibrary
endif
```

How can I do it?
The answers in SO [Makefile ifeq logical or](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656425/makefile-ifeq-logical-or) or [How to Use of Multiple condition in 'ifeq' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451477/how-to-use-of-multiple-condition-in-ifeq-statement) gives otherway of doing.

Comment: The second link you provided seems to be specific to an AND condition. But the first example you linked, using a filter, should work for you. Did you try it?

Answer (score 3):

You cant use a logical OR operator, there [simply isnt one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8296723/is-there-a-logical-or-operator-for-the-ifneq), hence having to use another way of doing it - like those suggested in the posts you've already found. The way I prefer to do it is with filter, as suggested in the [first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656425/makefile-ifeq-logical-or) you gave.

In your case it would look like this

```
ifneq (,$(filter on,$(TAG1)$(TAG2)))
LD_FLAGS += -ltestlibrary
endif
```

This concatenates both your tags, filters them for 'on', and compares them to an empty string, so if either tag is on then the comparison would be false and the `LD_FLAGS += -ltestlibrary` code would run.

Answer (score 3):

One can use filter for OR operator use in MakeFile.
For your case the condition will be like:

`ifneq ($(filter on,$(TAG1) $(TAG2)),)
LD_FLAGS += -ltestlibrary
endif`

[Please refer this link for GNU make functions for transforming text](http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/make/make_8.html#SEC73)

Answer (score 1):

Note that `ifeq ($(x),$(filter $(x),4 6))` will catch the case where x is not defined at all.

If you want to catch `x==4 || x==6` this will do trick:

```
ifneq ($(filter $(GCC_MINOR),4 6),)
   # do stuff
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

see my answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625323/using-ifeq-with-multiple-options/44333185#44333185)

if you want to check if x=4 or x=6

```
ifeq ($(x),$(filter $(x),4 6))   
   x is either 4 or 6. do whatever you like with it
else  
   x is neither 4 nor 6  
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Use shell, and then you can construct any complicated condition.

For example:

```
target:
ifneq "" "$(shell [ ! -e aaa.txt ] && [ -e bbb.txt ]  && echo 123)"
        @echo aaa.txt not exist and bbb.txt exist
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Should this not be, "ifeq" rather than "ifneq" ? like below?

```
ifeq ($(filter $(GCC_MINOR),4 6),)
   # do stuff
endif
```