# Logical "OR" condition in Makefile ifeq for a single parameter

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9802777/) showing how to implement the OR logic to check for different values for a flag.

But I just want to pass a single param without values (`start`, not `start=yes`) to 2 make commands: `run` and `run_whatever` *(example names)*

For the `run` command I am using:

```
ifeq (run,$(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)))
  # use the rest as arguments for "run"
  RUN_ARGS := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS))
  # ...and turn them into do-nothing targets
  $(eval $(RUN_ARGS):;@:)
endif
```

And

```
run:
    ./myprogram $(RUN_ARGS)
```

And I want to extend the ifeq condition to support:

```
run_whatever:
    ./myotherprogram $(RUN_ARGS)
```

And call them like: `make run start`, `make run_whatever start`

Comment: Sorry but I don't quite understand.  You say you want to _pass a single param without values_.  Do you mean you want to just run `make run` or `make run_whatever` without any "extra arguments" (e.g. you don't need `RUN_ARGS` at all)?

Comment: @MadScientist Sorry, edited for clarity. I'm trying to call them like this: `make run start`, `make run version`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation you can use:

```
ifeq (,$(filter-out run run_whatever,$(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS))))
```